# Jquery Mobile Form not aligned

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, layout

Please see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/McN99/) for an example.

The current email address is positioned high on the line and i'm not sure how to bring it down lower.  I've tried style="vertical-align:middle;" in a few places but it hasn't worked. Not sure what else to do.

Many thanks!

```
<form action="blahblah.php" method="post">
<div class="somestyling">
        <h2 style="text-align:center;">New Email Address</h2>

    <div class="ui-field-contain">
        <label for="current_email">Current Email:</label>
        <div id="current_email">me@work.com</div>
    </div>

    <div class="ui-field-contain">
        <label for="email">New Email:</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" />
    </div>

    <div class="ui-field-contain">
        <label for="password">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" />
    </div>

<button type="submit" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all">Update Email</button>
```

Comment: jQuery? In your Fiddle isn't a piece of jQuery

Comment: it's the class="ui-field-contain" and the jquery.css markup.  On the jsfiddle External Resource - jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this CSS:

```
#current_email{
    margin-top: 0.5em;
    line-height: 20px;
}
```

> Updated **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/kV5df/2/)**

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly.  I had wondered if there was a way of sorting it without having to individually adjust the <div>. But this works well. :)